# multiple self-contained filters applied during a single iteration

Tags: python, filter, functional-programming

Lets say I have a data structure that's very expensive to iterate through and I need to collect it's elements into lists depending on certain criteria.

```
#fake data.  pretend it's hard to access
import random
slowStruct = range(30)
random.shuffle(slowStruct)

def check1(x):
    return x < 3

def check2(x):
    return x > 15

def check3(x):
    return x < 25 and x > 20
```

The easiest way would be to use list comprehensions.  But this requires 3 iterations through the structure:

```
res1 = [node for node in slowStruct if check1(node)]
res2 = [node for node in slowStruct if check2(node)]
res3 = [node for node in slowStruct if check3(node)]
```

A faster way would be to use a loop and append to the result lists:

```
res1 = []
res2 = []
res3 = []
for node in slowStruct:
    if check1(node):
        res1.append(node)
    if check2(node):
        res2.append(node)
    if check3(node):
        res3.append(node)
```

Is there a functional-programming construct or idiom that can perform multiple filters, while only using a single iteration?

I can imagine it would look something like:

```
res1, res2, res3 = multiFilter(preds=[check1, check2, check3], iterable=slowStruct)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a clean way of doing so with comprehensions. If you want a loop, use a loop. A list comprehension should only make one list.

If you're willing to use a loop, you *are allowed* to encapsulate it:

```
def multi_filter(predicates, iterable):
    bins = [[] for _ in predicates]
    for item in iterable:
        for predicate, bin in zip(predicates, bins):
            if predicate(item):
                bin.append(item)

    return bins
```

Comment: This is a very clean and simple solution to a common problem. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a functional-programming construct or idiom that can perform
>   multiple filters, while only using a single iteration?

Yes, you can do this purely functional (although you will hit the max-recursion depth as python doesn't permit last call elimination).
The following code looks horrible, is purely functional, iterates only once over the iterable (but iterates over all conditions for each iteration, which is unavoidable):

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

slowStruct = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
conditions = [lambda x: x < 5,
      lambda x: x % 2,
      lambda x: x % 3]

multiFilter = lambda preds, iterable: (
    lambda f, preds, iterable: f (
        f,
        iterable,
        preds,
        [ [] for _ in preds]
        )
    ) (
        lambda f, l, cs, accs: f (
            f,
            l [1:],
            cs,
            [acc + (l [:1] if c (l [0] ) else [] )
                for acc, c in zip (accs, cs) ]
        ) if l else accs,
        preds,
        iterable
    )

print (multiFilter (conditions, slowStruct) )
```

Nota bene: Python wasn't made for functional programming (see LCO). Also PEP8 doesn't help for formatting functional code.

**To all commenters: I do not advocate this coding style, I am just trying to give a functional implementation (as requested by OP) that uses only one iteration.**

---

Edit: Might not be purely functional if you consider the destructive assignment inside the list comprehension.